# Twitterizer throwing an exception: Unexpected token when deserializing object: EndArray

Tags: c#, json, exception, twitter, twitterizer

I'm encountering a JSON (de)serialization exception when using Twitterizer's LookUp method. The exception states:

> Unexpected token when deserializing object: Integer

My code looks like

```
for (int i = 0; i < startedFollowing.Count; i++)
     {
       lookup.UserIds.Add(startedFollowing[i]);
       var yeniUser = TwitterUser.Lookup(token, lookup);
       friends followedfriend = new friends();
       followedfriend.name = yeniUser.ResponseObject[0].Name;
       followedfriend.screenName = yeniUser.ResponseObject[0].ScreenName;
       followedfriend.id = yeniUser.ResponseObject[0].Id;
       followedFriends.Add(followedfriend);
       lookup.UserIds.Clear();
     }
```

And the userId that I'm looking up is 36146022

Thanks in advance for your kind attention.

Stacktrace is like;

```
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1268
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 979
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, Object existingValue) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 434
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, Object existingValue) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 245
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonConverter converter, JsonContainerContract containerContract) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 230
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 806
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateAndPopulateList>b__0(IList l, Boolean isTemporaryListReference) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 749
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionUtils.CreateAndPopulateList(Type listType, Action`2 populateList) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\CollectionUtils.cs:line 242
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateList(JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 737
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String reference) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 500
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, Object existingValue) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 247
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonConverter converter, JsonContainerContract containerContract) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 230
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 126
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 526
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 492
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 925
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 885
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value) in c:\Dev\Releases\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 842
   at Twitterizer.Core.SerializationHelper`1.Deserialize(Byte[] webResponseData, DeserializationHandler deserializationHandler)
   at Twitterizer.Core.TwitterCommand`1.ExecuteCommand()
   at Twitterizer.Core.CommandPerformer.PerformAction[T](ICommand`1 command)
   at Twitterizer.TwitterUser.Lookup(OAuthTokens tokens, LookupUsersOptions options)
   at backupTwitter1.result.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\backupTwitter1\backupTwitter1\result.aspx.cs:line 129
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```